# How to assign to variable content of Three.js model file

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

When you export your model from Blender to Three.js you end up with a file with JSON data inside. I know two ways of loading this model from that file:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader()
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: '#8080a0'})
```

1.

```
loader.load('tower.json', function (geometry) {
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
})
```

2. Edit tower.js file and add

```
var tower =
```

in first line. Then you can load it with:

```
var towerModel = loader.parse(tower)
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(towerModel.geometry, material)
```

I like second solution more because using loader.load() function every time you want to create a mesh when you have thousands of meshes based on the same model is very slow and can easly kill your browser.

So my question is - can I get JSON data from tower.json file into a variable without editing the file manually? The best solution would be to get JSON data into a variable without making changes to the file.

Comment: Why not use method 1 once to load a geometry, and then create all the meshes from the same geometry?

Comment: Do you want many meshes to share the same geometry?

Comment: OK. Create 10 meshes from the same geometry, and add each one to the scene.

Comment: But I will have to create them inside callback function which I don't want to. I have geometry only in callback function, outside callback function model can be not loaded yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69427/discussion-between-westlangley-and-bartek-kosa).

Answer (score 0):

I would go for option 1.
It sounds very strange to add a loader to a source file. 
To keep things clean you should keep loaders and data sources (your model files) separated if you ask me.

Why would you reload the same model anyway. You should just store it in a variable and reuse it. It is a waste of CPU and memory to load the same geometry twice.

You can do easily something like this to optimize things. It is just a concept but I hope you get the idea:

```
// Storage for model files
myFiles = {
    tower: 'tower.json',
    car: 'car.json'
};

// Storage for loaded geometries
myModels = {
    tower: null,
    car: null
};

// Loader, loads only first time from file then from storage
var load = function( modelName ){
    if( myModels[modelName] === null ){
        loader.load(myFiles[modelName], function (geometry) {
            myModels[modelName] = geometry;
        });
    }

    var model = new THREE.Mesh(myModels[modelName], material)
    scene.add( model );
}
```

You can rework it how you think is best.

Comment: So what would you do if you had a loop in wich you will have to add 10000 meshes of one type and 3000 meshes of another type and 5000 on yet another type (from 3 different JSON files)?

Comment: Where did I add loader to a souce file? I changet it to normal javascript file by adding variable name to JSON data.

Comment: Your example will not work because when you are creating a mesh there is no geometry available because it didn't have time to load. Thats why you have to create mesh in callback function.